# Angularjs SidebySide Sum

Tags: angularjs, sum

I'm trying to produce a table with the sum of the values at the bottom.

Here HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="a in all |filter:'Gönderildi'" ng-init="$parent.yekun=yekun+a.total">
        <td>{{a.total}}</td>
    </tr>
    <td>{{yekun}}</td>
</table>
```

Output:

> 10
>   10
>   23
>   101023

Instead of adding the numbers it is showing them side-by-side. I tried to sum. By the way column is in int form.

Instead of 2+4=4 it shows "24".

Comment: I guess, the type of `a.total` or `yekun` is string. Check both of them are integers.

Comment: Thank you so much @harshad ! It worked!

Comment: @Harshad - add it as answer. So that others can get it when they search (also you gets points ! Don't miss it.)

Comment: Yes. Actually, I wasn't much sure about that. But, thanks. I will keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `a.total` or `yekun` is `string`.

Check both of them are integers.
If any one of them is string, it will concatenate them.